# jQuery .on does not work with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a site using Bootstrap 3.2.0. Because jQuery is fully supported I am using quite a lot of its code, however I seem to be unable to use .on(). The function does not seem to work, however, if instead I use older .delegate() everything works great.

Yes I am making syntax change appropriately when I try .on() vs .delegate().

This works:

```
$(document).delegate('.myEm', 'mouseover', function() {
    ...
});
```

and this doesn't:

```
$('.myEm').on('mouseover', function() {
    ...
});
```

I'm just wondering if this is something unique to my setup or someone else experienced this?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't possibly help you without seeing the code in question. My only guess is that you're using the wrong syntax for `.on`.

Comment: Please see added example.

Comment: I have this right above the bootstrap: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use event delegation with [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.myEm',function() {
```

Comment: OK, totally my bad. My jQuery version was ancient. Just changed to 2.1.1 and we're back in business. Also the syntax had it a bit backwards.

Comment: No, [1.11 is a current version of jQuery](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/05/01/jquery-1-11-1-and-2-1-1-released/). The 1.x versions are compatible with IE 6/7/8, while the 2.x versions strip out that compabibility for a smaller download.

Comment: Hah... good to know. But for some reason 1.11 did not work with .on() and I was testing on the latest FF.